# Subsetting values not adding up in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (`df`) in R.  All columns are character class.

```
> dim(df)
[1] 1000      6
```

I'm trying to remove rows where `df$entry == c("7795")`.

```
entries_to_remove <- subset(df, entry == c("7795"))
> dim(entries_to_remove)
[1] 35  6
```

So as you can see above, I have 35 entries to remove from the data frame.  However, when I go to remove these using subset, it doesn't remove the correct amount:

```
entries_to_remove <- subset(df, entry != c("7795"))
> dim(entries_to_remove)
[1] 648  6
```

The above command was supposed to remove 35 entries, but instead it removed 352.  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Check `subset(df, is.na(entry))`.

Comment: Do you have `NA`s in `df$entry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solutions didn't work, I do not think the issue is with NA.  However, I solved the problem myself.  It is a workaround but it worked:

```
# list the row numbers for the entries to remove
row_remove <- rownames(entries_to_remove )

# make a list of all the row numbers
all_rows <- 1:dim(df)[1]

# create a vector with only the rows to keep
subset_row <- all_rows[!(all_rows%in%row_remove)]

# subset the dataframe with these rows
df<- df[subset_row,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, which takes up just one line:

```
df[-which(grepl("7995", apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
```

RESULT:

```
  v1 entry1 entry2 entry3
2  2      5      5      2
3  3      2      4      2
4  4      2      3      1
6  6      1      2      1
7  7      2      4      4
8  8      4      5      5
9  9      5      1      5
```

DATA:

```
set.seed(121)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = 1:10,
  entry1 = c(sample(1:5, 9, replace = T), 7995),
  entry2 = c(sample(1:5, 4), 7995, sample(1:5, 5)),
  entry3 = c(7995, sample(1:5, 9, replace = T))
)

df[2:4] <- lapply(df[2:4], as.character) # convert to character, as in your data

df
   v1 entry1 entry2 entry3
1   1      1      2   7995
2   2      5      5      2
3   3      2      4      2
4   4      2      3      1
5   5      3   7995      2
6   6      1      2      1
7   7      2      4      4
8   8      4      5      5
9   9      5      1      5
10 10   7995      3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with NAs, some of the other solutions will work, but the easiest and I think most inutive is just to use %in% rather than ==

```
entries_to_remove <- subset(df, !(entry %in% c("7795")))
entries_to_remove <- subset(df, entry %in% c("7795"))
```

This should explain whats happening.  Notice how the ==, returns NA rather than FALSE.

```
> c( 5, 6, 7) == 5
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> c( 5, 6, 7 , NA) == 5
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
> c( 5, 6, 7 , NA) %in% 5
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and you can't subset using an NA